# On running my first simulation of castalia, i get the following error

Tags: omnet++

Simulation terminated with exit code: 139 Working directory: /home/roopali/omnetpp-4.6/samples/Castalia_proj/Simulations/Parameters Command line: ../../src/Castalia_proj -r 0 -n ..:../../src First_Obj.ini

Environment variables: PATH=/home/roopali/omnetpp-4.6/bin::/home/roopali/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/roopali/omnetpp-4.6/lib:: OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=/home/roopali/omnetpp-4.6/images

I have tried making this simulation using the steps on page https://chevy67.wordpress.com/tag/castalia/

Answer (score 0):

The blog post you linked (and tried to follow instructions from) refers to a **very old** version of Castalia. Follow the installation guidelines found in the official repo for Castalia:

https://github.com/boulis/Castalia

After you have installed Castalia successfully, read the manual (found again in the above link),  especially Chapter 3, to run your first simulation.